# Hide/show div by a radio button from another div

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a survey where you need to click radio buttons with value yes or no from a div and another div with another radio button will come out. These will continue until the 4th div came out.

The problem I'm encountering here is, when I **re-click** the **1st div button**, the **3rd** and **4th div won't hide**. And when i **re-click** the **2nd div button**, the **4th div won't hide** too. Below is my code.

```
<form class="px-4" method="post">
   <div class="form-check mb-2">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="response" value="yes" required onclick="showSolution('yes')">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="radio2Example1">Yes</label>
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="response" value="no" required onclick="showSolution('no')">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="radio2Example2">No</label>
   </div>
</form>

<!-- Recommendation Solution Section -->
<div id="solution" style="display: none;">
   <hr>
   <p style="text-align: left;" id="solutionText">
   <!-- Recommendation Solution will be displayed here -->
   </p>
   <div style="text-align: center;" id="additionalSolutionRadio">
   <!-- Additional Recommendation Solution Radio Buttons will be displayed here -->
   </div>
</div>

<!-- Additional Recommendation Solution Section -->
<div id="additionalSolution" style="display: none;">
   <hr>
   <p style="text-align: left;" id="additionalSolutionText">
   <!-- Additional Recommendation Solution will be displayed here -->
   </p>
   <div style="text-align: center;">
      <input type="radio" name="additional_solution" value="yes" required onclick="showAdditionalSolution2('yes')"> Yes 
      <input type="radio" name="additional_solution" value="no" required onclick="showAdditionalSolution2('no')"> No
   </div>
</div>

<!-- Additional Recommendation Solution 2 Section -->
<div id="additionalSolution2" style="display: none;">
   <hr>
   <p style="text-align: left;" id="additionalSolutionText2">
   <!-- Additional Recommendation Solution 2 will be displayed here -->
   </p>
</div>

<div class="w3-white w3-container w3-padding-32" style="margin-top:30px;padding-right:34px"><p class="w3-right"></a></p></div>

<script>
// Display solution based on user's response
function showSolution(response) {
  var solutionText = document.getElementById("solutionText");
  var solutionDiv = document.getElementById("solution");
  var additionalSolutionRadio = document.getElementById("additionalSolutionRadio");

  if (response === 'yes') {
    solutionText.innerHTML = "Problem Identified: Operating System Errors<br><br>" +
                            "Recommendation solution:<br><br>" +
                            "Have you used the system restore points to revert to a previously stable state? For macOS, have you used Disk Utility to repair disk errors?<br>";

    // Show the radio buttons for additional solution
    additionalSolutionRadio.innerHTML = '<input type="radio" name="additional_solution" value="yes" required onclick="showAdditionalSolution(\'yes\')"> Yes ' +
                                        '<input type="radio" name="additional_solution" value="no" required onclick="showAdditionalSolution(\'no\')"> No';

  } else {
    solutionText.innerHTML = "No problem identified. Your device is working fine.";
    // Hide the radio buttons for additional solution
    additionalSolutionRadio.innerHTML = '';
  }
  // Show the solution section
  solutionDiv.style.display = "block";
}

// Display additional solution based on user's selection
function showAdditionalSolution(additionalSolution) {
  var additionalSolutionText = document.getElementById("additionalSolutionText");
  var additionalSolutionDiv = document.getElementById("additionalSolution");

  if (additionalSolution === 'yes') {
    additionalSolutionText.innerHTML = "Additional Recommendation: <br><br>" +
                                      "Have you back up your data and consider reinstalling or refreshing the operating system?";
  } else {
    additionalSolutionText.innerHTML = "Try the system restore points to revert to a previously stable state. For macOS, used Disk Utility to repair disk errors.";
  }

  // Show the additional solution section
  additionalSolutionDiv.style.display = "block";
}

// Display additional solution 2 based on user's selection
function showAdditionalSolution2(additionalSolution2) {
  var additionalSolutionText2 = document.getElementById("additionalSolutionText2");
  var additionalSolutionDiv2 = document.getElementById("additionalSolution2");

  if (additionalSolution2 === 'yes') {
    additionalSolutionText2.innerHTML = "Additional Recommendation 2: <br><br>" +
                                      "Try to contact the technician if you still cannot solve the problem using the recommended solution.";
  } else {
    additionalSolutionText2.innerHTML = "Try to back up your data and consider reinstalling or refreshing the operating system.";
  }

  // Show the additional solution 2 section
  additionalSolutionDiv2.style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

I think I need to add the name attribute for both Additional Solution but I'm not quite sure how to add it.

I would appreciate it if someone can fix my mistakes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can hide anything you want  when you re-click any buttons.

```html
<form class="px-4" method="post">
  <div class="form-check mb-2">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="response" value="yes" required onclick="showSolution('yes')">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="radio2Example1">Yes</label>
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="response" value="no" required onclick="showSolution('no')">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="radio2Example2">No</label>
  </div>
</form>

<!-- Recommendation Solution Section -->
<div id="solution" style="display: none;">
  <hr>
  <p style="text-align: left;" id="solutionText">
    <!-- Recommendation Solution will be displayed here -->
  </p>
  <div style="text-align: center;" id="additionalSolutionRadio">
    <!-- Additional Recommendation Solution Radio Buttons will be displayed here -->
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Additional Recommendation Solution Section -->
<div id="additionalSolution" style="display: none;">
  <hr>
  <p style="text-align: left;" id="additionalSolutionText">
    <!-- Additional Recommendation Solution will be displayed here -->
  </p>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <input type="radio" name="additional_solution" value="yes" required onclick="showAdditionalSolution2('yes')"> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="additional_solution" value="no" required onclick="showAdditionalSolution2('no')"> No
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Additional Recommendation Solution 2 Section -->
<div id="additionalSolution2" style="display: none;">
  <hr>
  <p style="text-align: left;" id="additionalSolutionText2">
    <!-- Additional Recommendation Solution 2 will be displayed here -->
  </p>
</div>

<div class="w3-white w3-container w3-padding-32" style="margin-top:30px;padding-right:34px">
  <p class="w3-right">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>

<script>
  // Display solution based on user's response
  function showSolution(response) {
    var solutionText = document.getElementById("solutionText");
    var solutionDiv = document.getElementById("solution");
    var additionalSolutionRadio = document.getElementById("additionalSolutionRadio");
    var additionalSolutionDiv = document.getElementById("additionalSolution");
    var additionalSolutionDiv2 = document.getElementById("additionalSolution2");

    if (response === 'yes') {
      solutionText.innerHTML = "Problem Identified: Operating System Errors<br><br>" +
        "Recommendation solution:<br><br>" +
        "Have you used the system restore points to revert to a previously stable state? For macOS, have you used Disk Utility to repair disk errors?<br>";

      // Show the radio buttons for additional solution
      additionalSolutionRadio.innerHTML = '<input type="radio" name="additional_solution" value="yes" required onclick="showAdditionalSolution(\'yes\')"> Yes ' +
        '<input type="radio" name="additional_solution" value="no" required onclick="showAdditionalSolution(\'no\')"> No';

    } else {
      solutionText.innerHTML = "No problem identified. Your device is working fine.";
      // Hide the radio buttons for additional solution
      additionalSolutionRadio.innerHTML = '';
      additionalSolutionDiv.style.display = "none";
      additionalSolutionDiv2.style.display = "none";
    }
    // Show the solution section
    solutionDiv.style.display = "block";
  }

  // Display additional solution based on user's selection
  function showAdditionalSolution(additionalSolution) {
    var additionalSolutionText = document.getElementById("additionalSolutionText");
    var additionalSolutionDiv = document.getElementById("additionalSolution");
    var additionalSolutionDiv2 = document.getElementById("additionalSolution2");
    additionalSolutionDiv2.style.display = "none";
    if (additionalSolution === 'yes') {
      additionalSolutionText.innerHTML = "Additional Recommendation: <br><br>" +
        "Have you back up your data and consider reinstalling or refreshing the operating system?";
    } else {
      additionalSolutionText.innerHTML = "Try the system restore points to revert to a previously stable state. For macOS, used Disk Utility to repair disk errors.";
    }

    // Show the additional solution section
    additionalSolutionDiv.style.display = "block";
  }

  // Display additional solution 2 based on user's selection
  function showAdditionalSolution2(additionalSolution2) {
    var additionalSolutionText2 = document.getElementById("additionalSolutionText2");
    var additionalSolutionDiv2 = document.getElementById("additionalSolution2");

    if (additionalSolution2 === 'yes') {
      additionalSolutionText2.innerHTML = "Additional Recommendation 2: <br><br>" +
        "Try to contact the technician if you still cannot solve the problem using the recommended solution.";
    } else {

      additionalSolutionText2.innerHTML = "Try to back up your data and consider reinstalling or refreshing the operating system.";
    }

    // Show the additional solution 2 section
    additionalSolutionDiv2.style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
```